# La ruta de Error404 en react router dom aparece en todas las rutas

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

tengo un problema y es que estoy haciendo un programa que tenga diferentes rutasen react router dom y eh hecho que las rutas no especificadas las redirija a la pagina Error404 el problema es que esa misma pagina aparece en todas las demas rutas, esten especificadas o no, por ejemplo la de Home.
Si muevo la ruta path="*" fuera del provider no lo muestra :/
De antemano gracias

```js
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Editar from "./Pages/Editar";
import LoginProvider from "./Context/LoginProvider";
import Error404 from "./Pages/Error404";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <LoginProvider>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/editar/:id" component={Editar} />
            <Route path="*" component={Error404} />
          </LoginProvider>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

proba con esto:

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Editar from "./Pages/Editar";
import LoginProvider from "./Context/LoginProvider";
import Error404 from "./Pages/Error404";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <LoginProvider>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/editar/:id" component={Editar} />
            <Redirect to="/error404" component={Error404} /> //donde dice to="" escribi correctamente tu direccion donde vas a mostrar el componente Error404
          </LoginProvider>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu código o al menos las partes relevantes, indicando al OP las secciones en las que debería prestar atención ya que así fomentas el copy/paste. En caso de ser necesario, es buena idea colocar enlaces a documentación oficial.

Answer (score -1):

Veo que tu codigo parece estar bien segun la documentacion de react-router-dom, me queda la duda de si tu context (que asumo que es un context jeje) LoginProvider puede estar interviniendo de alguna forma. Podrias intentar ubicarlo fuera del router

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router- 
dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Editar from "./Pages/Editar";
import LoginProvider from "./Context/LoginProvider";
import Error404 from "./Pages/Error404";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <LoginProvider>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/editar/:id" component={Editar} />
            <Route path="*" component={Error404} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </LoginProvider>
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Adicionalmente te recomendaria uses un esque mas ordenado para las rutas, te comparto el que utilizo yo siempre para mis proyectos con react-router-dom

archivo config que contiene la data de las rutas

import Home from "../pages/Home"
import Error404 from "../pages/Error404"
import ruta1 from "../pages/ruta1 ";
import ruta2 from "../pages/ruta2";

```
export default [
    {
      path: "/",
      exact: true,
      page: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/ruta1/:id",
      exact: true,
      page: ruta1
    },
    {
      path: "/ruta1/",
      exact: true,
      page: ruta1
    },
    {
      path: "/ruta2/",
      exact: true,
      page: ruta2
    },
    {
      path: "*",
      page: Error404
    }
];
```

y un archivo Rountig que usa el anterior para generar las rutas

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Config from './Config';

  export default function Rounting() {
     return (
       <Router>
        <Switch>
        {Config.map((ruta, i) => (
            <Route 
            key={i} 
            path={ruta.path} 
            exact={ruta.exact}>
                <ruta.page />
            </Route>             
        ))}         
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
 }
```

Comment: Cuando saco el Route del context no aparece aunque la ruta esté o no especificada, sí, también se me hace raro como esta actuando y no le encuentro lógica, esta bastante bueno el manejo de tus rutas :D}